# Desktop background mysteriously changed

Tags: kde, plasma, desktop-background

When I booted my computer this morning, the wrong wallpaper appeared. The image file for my regular wallpaper was still where it was supposed to be, and it's still available in the Plasma Desktop Folder Settings; however, the desktop was showing instead the Altai wallpaper which I suspect is the default wallpaper for my version of KDE. I'm running Ubuntu Studio 21.10.

This is a minor annoyance; I've easily restored my regular wallpaper. It's still a bit unsettling to have a system setting change for no apparent reason (I didn't mess with the config or run any updates yesterday). Just wondering if anybody else has encountered that kind of glitch or has any idea what may have caused it.

Comment: See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1755537/288643). KDE doesn't always detect display outputs in the same order each boot, so it can get confused as to which screen should display what (even if you only use one screen). You can often swap the contents back to the expected screen.